# How to resize a centered image on a canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

The code I have below will take an uploaded image and center it on a canvas, it is working but I'm unable to change the size of the actual image. I want to be able to upload an image and then scale it down by a percentage or pixel with it centered.

The way it works right now is you upload an image and it automatically gets populated on the canvas. The final product will return a base64 string that I will convert using C#.

Any help would be great, thanks.

[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/Joe_Scotto/pen/LWPeGE)

HTML:

```
<input type="file">
```

Javascript:

```
$("input").on("change", function(e) {
  var file = this.files[0];
  if (!file) return;
  var fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = () => {
    var image = new Image();
    image.onload = () => {
      canvas.width = image.width;
      canvas.height = image.height;
      var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

      // Change Background
      context.beginPath();
      context.rect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
      context.fillStyle = "#7D8491";
      context.fill();

      // Draw Logo      
      context.drawImage(image, canvas.width / 2 - image.width / 2,
        canvas.height / 2 - image.height / 2);

      // Append to body
      $("body").append(canvas);

      // Open base64 url
      //window.open(canvas.toDataURL("image/png"));
    };
    image.src = fileReader.result;
  };
  fileReader.readAsDataURL(file);
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply had to divide both the position and the actual width/height by the percentage I wanted to scale the image down.

```
// Draw Logo      
context.drawImage(
    image, 
    canvas.width / 2 - image.width * .75 / 2,
    canvas.height / 2 - image.height * .75 / 2,
    image.width * .75, image.height * .75
);
```